# Get data from Google Ads API using App Script

Tags: javascript, rest, google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I wanna get out campaigns reports using Google Rest API and it does'nt work in Google ads Apps script.

My code:

```
function main() {
  
const API_VERSION = "12";
const CUSTOMER_ID = "***"; //contais real custommer ID
const DEVELOPER_TOKEN = "***"; //contais real developper ID
const MANAGER_CUSTOMER_ID = "***"; //contais real manager ID
const OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN = ""; //contais real ACCES TOKEN

const data = {
  "pageSize": 10000,
  "query": "SELECT ad_group_criterion.keyword.text, ad_group_criterion.status FROM ad_group_criterion WHERE ad_group_criterion.type = 'KEYWORD' AND ad_group_criterion.status = 'ENABLED'"
};

const url = `https://googleads.googleapis.com/v${API_VERSION}/customers/${CUSTOMER_ID}/googleAds:search`;
const options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "developer-token": DEVELOPER_TOKEN,
    "login-customer-id": MANAGER_CUSTOMER_ID,
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN}`
  },
  body:  JSON.stringify(data), 
  "muteHttpExceptions": true
};

Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options));
}
```

Result error:
{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
"details": [
{
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.ads.googleads.v12.errors.GoogleAdsFailure",
"errors": [
{
"errorCode": {
"queryError": "UNEXPECTED_END_OF_QUERY"
},
"message": "Error in query: unexpected end of query."
}
],
"requestId": "zKBR9-dJoG9NWAx3iJea2g"
}
]
}
}

But query is valid https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v11/query_validator
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPmaT.png)

Could you plese help?

Thanks

I wanna get out campaigns reports using Google Rest API and it does'nt work. My code and result is above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation of [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app), 'body' is not the correct option for passing in the query. You want 'payload'.

```
const options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "developer-token": DEVELOPER_TOKEN,
    "login-customer-id": MANAGER_CUSTOMER_ID,
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN}`
  },
  payload:  JSON.stringify(data), 
  "muteHttpExceptions": true
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I forget about js and app script differences. ‍♀️